# Is there a way to specify partitioning in Apache Arrow parquet files without using the hive-style "=" in the file paths?

Tags: hive, apache-arrow

I am working on a project where I need to create and analyze parquet files using Apache Arrow. The environment I'm working with does not allow "=" in file paths, which the hive naming convention forces, e.g. "year=2007". Is there a way with Arrow to create partitioned parquet files without using the hive-style file naming convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment Arrow supports both "hive" and "directory" schemes.  The hive scheme, as you mentioned, is `column_name=value`.  There is no way at the moment to change the `=` character to a different separator but it sounds like a good JIRA ticket if you want to make one.

The directory scheme will encode just the value and will not need to use `=` so that may work for you.  It is a slightly different scheme as it does not store the column name as part of the directory name.  So you will need to supply that column name when you are reading the data back.

I'm not sure if you are using pyarrow or C++-arrow.  In pyarrow the directory scheme is talked about [here](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.partitioning.html).  There is also a pyarrow [example](https://arrow.apache.org/cookbook/py/io.html#writing-partitioned-datasets) writing a dataset with the directory scheme in the cookbook.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
import numpy.random

data = pa.table({"day": numpy.random.randint(1, 31, size=100),
                 "month": numpy.random.randint(1, 12, size=100),
                 "year": [2000 + x // 10 for x in range(100)]})
# The directory scheme is the default if no flavor is specified
partitioning=ds.partitioning(pa.schema([("year", pa.int16())]))
ds.write_dataset(data, "./partitioned", format="parquet", partitioning=partitioning)
```

This will result in files like:

```
./partitioned/2000/part-0.parquet
./partitioned/2001/part-1.parquet
./partitioned/2002/part-2.parquet
./partitioned/2003/part-3.parquet
./partitioned/2004/part-4.parquet
./partitioned/2005/part-6.parquet
./partitioned/2006/part-5.parquet
./partitioned/2007/part-7.parquet
./partitioned/2008/part-8.parquet
./partitioned/2009/part-9.parquet
```

Comment: Thank you. I recall seeing something like this a while back but missed it in the docs this time. The inconvenience is that when providing these files to others, they need to know the variable names that were partitioned on, which is slightly inconvenient. I'll open a ticket for a "modified" hive style and see if it has any traction.